# Increment JSON score variable in python?

Tags: python, html, json

I'm using a JSON file for a question and answer quiz and one of my keys is named "score". I was wondering how I would increment the score if the answer was correct? I know a lot of people already know this, but I can't find an answer.

```
{% for object in quiz %}
  {% if object.answer == "Mercedes" %}
    {{score+1}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I assume it's something like this? Please help.

Comment: So, you want to increment `score` key in JSON file? I mean you want to modify JSON file?

Comment: You need to specify what your code looks like here. Is this in a Django or Flask template? Is the number handling happening in a view or a utility? Is the JSON file being changed or is the HTML being changed?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be different for Django/Flask, but in normal Python you would just use `score += 1` which is equivalent to `score = score + 1`.